# Unable to deploy a second ingress controller using helm in Azure Kubernetes Cluster ( AKS )

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I deployed one ingress controller in a namespace by running the command:

```
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace kk \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

When I run the same command in another namespace I get the below error:

```
Error: Failed to download "ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

I am pretty sure we can install multiple ingress controller in one Kubernetes cluster but I am unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: That says 'failed to download' -- what makes you think that this is an installation issue?

Comment: Did you try the hint => `helm repo update`

Comment: Do you use a different name for the second ingress controller?

Answer (score 1):

It's all about your internet connection. I've had the same problem.
Try using the specific version; that may help:

```
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --version 3.7.1 --debug
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Following the hint by typing the command `helm repo update` solved the problem for me.